# How to understand if a video is playing in browser?

Tags: video, browser

I'd like to know if there is a way to understand from **outside** a browser if there is a video playing in the browser itself. It would be great if it'd be possible to do this for every browser.
I thought that maybe this could be done inspecting the files created by the browser when the video is playing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flash videos, one way I can think of is to see if a flash player is running. However, that's not very convincing because flash player's could be running for flash games as well.

Comment: And for flash banners too, I think.